# zend-framework how to Localize Zend_Date

Tags: zend-framework, localization, calendar, zend-date, zend-locale

how to localize the Zend_Date

when i wrote

```
Zend_Debug::dump(Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('type', 'en_US'));
```

i got long array some of its elements

```
  .
  .
  ["hebrew"] => string(15) "Hebrew Calendar"
  ["indian"] => string(24) "Indian National Calendar"
  ["islamic"] => string(16) "Islamic Calendar"
  ["islamic-civil"] => string(22) "Islamic-Civil Calendar"
  ["japanese"] => string(17) "Japanese Calendar"
  .
  .
```

so i think **Islamic Calendar** , **Hebrew Calendar** is supported how to reach this features?

also it is commented in this page **http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-4291**

Comment: **Exact** duplicate of [Calendars in zend framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476675/calendars-in-zend-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't have a look at the documentation, that's always the first thing you should do: [**Working with Dates and Times**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.date.datesandtimes.html).

So with **Zend_Locale_Format** you can normalize and convert date and time for different locale.

E.g. you can normalize a data by locale like this:

```
  $locale = new Zend_Locale('de_AT');

  $date = Zend_Locale_Format::getDate('13.04.2005 22:14:55',
                                       array('date_format' =>
                                           Zend_Locale_Format::STANDARD,
                                       'locale' => $locale)   
  );
```

Hope that helps ;)
.
So this is the answer I got from him: you should have a look at [**WebCal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcal).

Comment: you say "Why you don't have a look at the documentation" i say why you don't look at the question i'm as asking about calendar not just a format 31/3/2011 gregorian calendar is 26/4/1432 in hijri islamic calendar. have you got it?

Comment: Do you want to display a calender?

Comment: the default calendar of Zend_Date is gregorian. is countries like Audi Arabia the calendar used is hijri[Islamic] . how can i support this calendar type in zend-framework?

Comment: @Ahmed: I don't think it is supported yet. But I could be wrong. I believe there was a proposal `Zend_Calendar` which would do what you want. But I can't see the status of the proposal, because the service is down now.

Comment: I have contacted the author of Zend_Calender. Let's wait for his answer.

Comment: nice work thanks a lot for your help. i sent him an email yesterday but no reply till now. i'm waiting...